# What would gravity be like on the surface of a right rectangular prism?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, geometry

Let's assume there is a right rectangular prism floating about in space, what would the gravity be like across its 6 flat surfaces?

Let's assume that this right rectangular prism has a constant density and has a mass equal to Earth's. At any point on the surface of this prism, would gravity vary? That is, would it be an extreme variation than compared to one traveling across the surface of Earth? How extreme would this differential be?

I've added a rectangular prism with the lengths in mind.

[image: A rectangular prism with the specific dimensions]

Comment: A more specific answer would be possible if you had information about the length of the sides. For example, how the force would vary across a certain side. I can tell you that the gravitational force will always point towards the center of the prism, so on each face you will be pulled to the center of that face.

Comment: @AaronStevens I've added the lengths, thank you.

Comment: I'll be able to give a more involved answer in the morning if no one else has.

Comment: Here are some related items, but this question about the field itself is new and not a duplicate. [Could you stably orbit around a square (cubic) body? Would the orbit destabilize automatically if not corrected by input?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/20925/12102) where I discuss one method to calculate the field and give a few references, and also [Another way to evaluate the gravitational force from a uniform cube?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/26537/17869) that give some additional alternative methods. This is a very interesting question, as will be the answer!